# How to get all the rbac groups a user is part of in a particular subscription in azure

Tags: azure

I am using Get-AzureADGroupMember but it is giving me the list of all groups in all subscription not a particular subscription... How can i filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use [`Get-AzRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-2.7.0) PowerShell Cmdlet. From the documentation page:

> Lists Azure RBAC role assignments at the specified scope. By default
>   it lists all role assignments in the selected Azure subscription. Use
>   respective parameters to list assignments to a specific user, or to
>   list assignments on a specific resource group or resource.

Comment: My user is a part of group, so even if I use above command, display name will come for group..not for a particular user.... I want to get all the rbac roles a user has in a particular subscription

Comment: If a user is in a group, first thing you will need to find the group user is part of and then get the RBAC role assignment for that group. A user will have the same RBAC role assignment.

Comment: Yes, so to get all the groups a user is part of.. I have used Get-AzureADGroupMember, but i cannot filter it for a particular environment... It's getting all the environment's group which is  dev, prod, test

Comment: An Azure AD doesn't know about Azure Subscription. It's just a user store (in a manner of speaking). An Azure Subscription has a trust relationship with Azure AD in the sense that it authenticates a user in an Azure AD. For authorization, it relies on RBAC.

Comment: Okay thanks, I have filtered it on the basis of scope using Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment after getting all the groups a user is part of.